# Setting good font-size for 980px mobile viewport (without meta[@name="viewport"])

Tags: html, css, viewport, font-size, device-width

I have a very big website many different elements and generation of content.  It does not seem practical to unconditionally add a `meta[@name="viewport"]` to the HTML of all the pages, because then it might break down various elements, and/or make some of the logos or graphics unnecessarily large.

We'd instead like to use a CSS media query like `@media (width: 980px), (hover: none) {…}`, and increase the `font-size` of actual text.  This can partially be done automatically through [`-webkit-text-size-adjust`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW16), however, the feature seems 100% half-baked in that it simply accepts a percentage for the zoom without consideration of how big or small the viewport is, which would vary even on a single device w/ landscape vs. portrait mode.

- Question: *Is there a way to determine the appropriate `font-size` that I should use in my `980px` viewport to match the default `font-size` that would have been set had `viewport`'s `width` been set to `device-width`?*